# how to create polygon with ServerVector response of openlayer 3

Tags: ajax, json, openlayers-3

this Code is working fine for loading map, but I want to create polygon from json and data get data by ajax request (in json array).

I am new guy to openlayer 3. I do not get way that how to create polygon from json data that got by ajax request.

If you know any other way then please suggest me(but only by using openlayers 3).

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
       var url = 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
       'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
       'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
       '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
     maxZoom: 19
    })),
 projection: 'EPSG:3857'
 });

 var loadFeatures = function(response) {
    vectorSource.addFeatures(vectorSource.readFeatures(response));
 };

 var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: vectorSource,
     style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
           width: 2
        })
     })
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
        imagerySet: 'Aerial',
        key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3'
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-8908887.277395891, 5381918.072437216],
        maxZoom: 19,
        zoom: 12
    })
});
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Is it a WFS like in the [example](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs.html)?